# JQuery Mobile - Clone entire body content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have been trying to clone the entire HTML within the  tags.  However when I do although the appearance on screen is correct none of the links work.

Here is a fiddle:
[Here is a fiddle][1]

```
  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/a4poster/ntkxpd63/
```

The idea is to store data locally so when the user presses the button it saves to localStorage (I haven't added that here yet) as until I can get the links working it is not worth doing.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use something like stringify for cloning.

For example:

```js
const dom_objects = document.querySelectorAll ('body> div');
const string_to_save = JSON.stringify (dom_objects);
localStorage.setItem ('foo', string_to_save);
```